# SpringData (4.x) elastic doesn't serialize entity properly

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.1-RELEASE and elastic 7.6.2 . While storing entities , some of the objects are not getting serialized properly. It is stored as below:

````
"ownerResource": {
"_class": "x.xxx.xxx.Resource$HibernateProxy$b6cxNN75"
}, ```
````

Comment: Few of the objects were lazy loaded , when I removed the fetch type then they seem to serialize properly, but I cannot do this for every entity as this would impact the performance. Can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be: do not use the same entities you store in a relational database to store them in Elasticsearch.

What you get from Hibernate or JPA is an entity which basically is a proxy to your entity class with the ability to populate properties by fetching them lazy.

And this is what you store in Elasticsearch, the dynamically created proxy class.

If you do not load the properties of your entities before storing them in Elasticsearch, what do you want to have stored there?

So create a class for your Elasticsearch entity, copy the relevant/needed data from your JPA entity and store that in Elasticsearch.